# Checking if UTD parameter has values in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, user-defined-types

I want to check if a parameter with some User-Defined Table Type has values or is NULL but i'm receiving the following error

```
Msg 137, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SearchByWord, Line 63 [Batch Start Line 7]
Must declare the scalar variable "@Words".
```

The stored procedure is as follow (only the relevant part)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SearchByWord]
(
    @Words Word_List READONLY
)
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- some DECLARE and SET

    IF @Words IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
       -- stuff
    END

    -- more stuff
END
```

The User-Defined Table type is

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[Word_List] AS TABLE(
    [element] [varchar](512) NULL
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @Words)
```

Not

```
IF @Words IS NOT NULL
```

The table valued parameter will always be present and can't be `NULL` like a scalar parameter.

If you call `exec [dbo].[SearchByWord]` without passing anything for the parameter the result is that `@Words` will be empty table.

Comment: I feel like a dump, i completely forgot about the EXISTS clausule ... thanks